# Align items in WPF ListBox in horizontal direction

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox

I want to make the images I add align horizontally but anything I tried keeps make the items align vertically

So my items align like this ->
[image]

But i want something like this ->
[image]

This is what I tried ->

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1">
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>
        </StackPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate >
            <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                <Image  Height="100"  Width="100" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ConvertedData}" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: better use WrapPanel, not StackPanel in ItemsPanelTemplate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use WrapPanel in ItemsPanelTemplate. ItemsPanel is the one which is resposible for layout of items inside ItemsControl. Panel in ItemTemplate controls the layout of individual items.

also use ItemContainerStyle to modify properties of ListBoxItems.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <Image  Height="100"  Width="100" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding ConvertedData}" /> 
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```